# How can I show that the following tends to a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> If $\widehat{\sigma}^2_n\xrightarrow{P}\sigma^2$and $\sqrt{n}\left(\widehat{\mu}_n - \mu\right)/\sigma\xrightarrow{d}N(0, 1)$, then show that $\sqrt{n}\left(\widehat{\mu}_n - \mu\right)/\sqrt{\widehat{\sigma}^2_n}\xrightarrow{d}N(0, 1)$.

Is this question as simple as stating that as n tends to infinity, the sample variance also tends to the true variance and therefore the distribution must also tend to a normal one? If this is not the case, why is that so?

Comment: I think Slutsky's theorem can handle this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{ \sqrt{n}\left(\widehat{\mu}_n - \mu\right)}{\sqrt{\widehat{\sigma}^2_n}}
\end{align}
The numerator converges in distribution to $\operatorname N(0,\sigma^2).$ The denominator converges in probability to $\sigma\ne0.$

So [Slutksy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) does it.